# How can I use LINQ to return a list with multiple records for any object that is linked to multiple secondary objects?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of `Form` objects and each `Form` object is linked to a `Subject` object via link tables. If one of those forms is linked to multiple subjects, how can I use LINQ to return a list of forms where each form that has multiple subjects appears in the list twice with the relevant subject id? Furthermore, how can I then group together forms in that list that have the same `TypeId` and `SubjectId`?

Here is my code to reproduce the situation I'm talking about:

```
public class Form
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TypeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<FormSubjectLink> FormSubjectLinks { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; } // to return the subject id to once isolated
}

public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class FormSubjectLink
{
    public int FormId { get; set; }
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
}

public List<Form> forms = new List<Form>() {
new Form { Id = 1, TypeId = 1, Name = "FormA1", FormSubjectLinks = new List<FormSubjectLink>() { new FormSubjectLink { FormId = 1, SubjectId = 1 } } },
new Form { Id = 2, TypeId = 1, Name = "FormA2", FormSubjectLinks = new List<FormSubjectLink>() { new FormSubjectLink { FormId = 2, SubjectId = 1 } } },
new Form { Id = 3, TypeId = 1, Name = "FormA3", FormSubjectLinks = new List<FormSubjectLink>() { new FormSubjectLink { FormId = 3, SubjectId = 2 } } },
new Form { Id = 4, TypeId = 2, Name = "FormB1", FormSubjectLinks = new List<FormSubjectLink>() { new FormSubjectLink { FormId = 4, SubjectId = 1 }, new FormSubjectLink { FormId = 4, SubjectId = 2 }}}};
```

What I would like to do here is take my list of and return `IEnumerable<IGrouping<(TypeId,SubjectId),Form>>` with the following items:

| TypeId | SubjectId | Form Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: base on your example can do in one line forms.GroupBy(s => new { s.TypeId, s.SubjectId }).Select(s => new { TypeID = s.Key.TypeId, SubjectId = s.Key.SubjectId,  cnt = s.Count()  })

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume each form will only contain form subject links with `FormId` equal to that form's `Id`.

If you use LINQ query syntax, it is very straightforward:

```
var result = from form in forms
    from link in form.FormSubjectLinks 
    // for each link in each form
    group form by (form.TypeId, link.SubjectId) into groups
    // group the forms by the type id and subject id
    select groups;

foreach (var x in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(x.Key);
    foreach(var y in x) {
        Console.WriteLine(y);
    }
}
```

Sample output (using the `ToString` formatting of `record`s):

```
(1, 1)
Form { Id = 1, TypeId = 1, Name = FormA1, FormSubjectLinks = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FormSubjectLink], SubjectId = 0 }
Form { Id = 2, TypeId = 1, Name = FormA2, FormSubjectLinks = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FormSubjectLink], SubjectId = 0 }
(1, 2)
Form { Id = 3, TypeId = 1, Name = FormA3, FormSubjectLinks = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FormSubjectLink], SubjectId = 0 }
(2, 1)
Form { Id = 4, TypeId = 2, Name = FormB1, FormSubjectLinks = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FormSubjectLink], SubjectId = 0 }
(2, 2)
Form { Id = 4, TypeId = 2, Name = FormB1, FormSubjectLinks = System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FormSubjectLink], SubjectId = 0 }
```